# How to change preference of Known Wi-Fi Networks on Linux?

Tags: wifi, gnome, networkmanager

I was recently transferred from one team to another in my company. The two teams' offices are very close so I can still catch the Wi-Fi in my previous room. It is still saved in my Linux laptop because sometimes I need to go visit my old team for collaborative work.

However when I turn on Wi-Fi while sitting on my new desk, it connects to my old Wi-Fi although its signal is much weaker than my new one which is right next to me. Is there a hidden preference value designated to each hotspot that is not visible on GUI? If so, how can I edit the scores so that my new one comes on top?

I use GNOME and my Wi-Fi manager is NetworkManager.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/165679/how-to-manage-available-wireless-network-priority ?

Comment: not the accepted answer, the first answer mentioning `nmcli`

Comment: Yeah that's also supported in the graphical `nm-connection-editor` by now.